# Boolean test returning false when it should be true?

Tags: java, boolean

I am going through a list of questions on a past examination paper.
One of the questions is of type boolean.

It should return false if the name is not Thomas, and true if it is.

Here is my code:

```
public class QuestionTwo
{   
String name;

public static void main(String [] args){

    System.out.println(nameTest("Thomas"));   
}
public static boolean nameTest(String name){
    if(!name.equals("Thomas"));
    return false; 
 }
}
```

As you can see my code should return true, but it keeps returning false?
Can someone tell me where I seem to have gone wrong with my code please?
Please forgive any silly errors found as I am still learning.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolon

```
    if(!name.equals("Thomas")) return false;
```

The way you have written it, it is two separate statements. First, if name not equals Thomas then do nothing. Then second, return false.

Comment: @PrimalScientist: Note that Zutty has moved `return false;` to the same line as the `if`. This is **completely unnecessary**. Just removing the semicolon is all you need to do. Most of the time, you would then either indent the `return false;` line a bit under the `if` so it's visually apparent it's subordinate to that, and frequently put `{` and `}` around it, like this: http://pastie.org/6459258 Or, of course, move it to the same line as Zutty has done, which some people consider acceptable in limited cases (such as this one).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Pastie.org seems pretty interesting? Another good site for learning?

Comment: No, if you just remove the semicolon, the code fails to compile.  Need to add `return true;` at the end.

Answer (score 6):

remove the **semicolon** at the end of `if statement`.

```
 if(!name.equals("Thomas"))
```

Also good practice is to do `equals test` this way:

```
 if(!"Thomas".equals(name))
```

In this case, if name is **null** you wouldn't get **NPE**.

Answer (score 3):

> [the method] should return false if the name is not Thomas, and true if it is.

You do not need an `if` at all:

```
 public static boolean nameTest(String name){
     return name.equals("Thomas");
 }
```

In general, `boolean` expressions are easier to read without `if`s and `== true` / `== false` around them. Every time you see returning `true` or `false` from a branch of an `if`, you should consider rewriting it without the `if` statement.

Comment: In the question there is no if statement, I thought that I would have to put this in. This the first time I have seen this type of boolean statement. Many thanks.

Comment: This is something to remember then!! Thing is I / we (the class) have always associated boolean statements with the if statement. 
It might be something that our lecturer may be looking at further down the line to do it this way??
This is really good you know. Thanks.

Comment: @PrimalScientist Yes, this sort of things is what the lecturer will teach you at some point. The important thing to remember is that `boolean` expressions are expressions, too - they are not only for use in `if`s and `while`s, but they can be assigned, returned, compared to each other, and so on.

Comment: Many thanks for this great feedback. All this information has been really great and is something I can build on.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Putting semicolon after if and return statements makes them separate statements.
Code should be like :

```
public class QuestionTwo {   
    String name;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(nameTest("Thomas"));   
    }

    public static boolean nameTest(String name){
        if(!"Thomas".eqauals(name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) And don't forget to accept answer you liked or which helped resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to return exactly whether the name equals Thomas. There is no need to do an if statement

```
public static boolean nameTest(String name){
  return name.equals("Thomas"); 
}
```

The other proposed solution:

```
if(!name.equals("Thomas")) return false;
```

won't compile, because there is no return value in case the name isn't Thomas.